# Extract number from String in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, awk

I want to extract a number from a string and use that number for future calculations

```
while IFS= read line ; do  

  if [[ "$line" == Content-Length* ]]
  then
  size=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')   
  echo "$size"
  let size=$size+1  
  echo "$size"
  break
  fi    
done <files
```

files has the line

```
Content-Length: 4806
```

but output looks like this

```
4806
+1")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
4806
```

i tried this for more than 5 hrs but could find why is this happening .can some one tell me why

Comment: I ran your script and it ran fine.

Comment: The file you are parsing has DOS line endings, which cause `$line` to end with a carriage return (`\r`). This carriage return winds up in the value of `size`, which the `let` statement chokes on. Notice the odd error where the text following `$size` appears at the beginning of the error message, not the end. The actual error token is `4806\r+1`.

Comment: Thanq @chepner but can u tell me how can i solve that problem

Comment: (Minor correction to my previous comment, the error token is `\r+1`. Too late to edit the comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `Content-Length: 4806` is actually a space-delimited pair of strings.

```
while read -r field value; do
    if [ "$field" = "Content-Length" ]; then
        echo "$size"
        echo "$((size+1))"
    fi
done < files
```

To solve the problem of DOS line endings, either run the file through `dos2unix` or some other tool to fix the line endings, or trim the carriage return using

```
size=${size%.}
```

which will remove the final character of `size` from its value. Fixing the file, rather than coding around it, is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace:

```
let size=$size+1
```

to

```
let size=$[$size+1]
```

or

```
let size=$[size+1]
```

or

```
let size++
```

or

```
let size=`expr $size + 1`
```

All example run fine on ubuntu 13.04 and you example too.

Comment: In Ubuntu you can remove the `let` and just use `((size++))`.  And you should not use back tics `` use parantheses `$()` like this `let size=$(expr $size + 1)`